# Background is not covering 100vh when expanding other divs

Tags: css, background, height

In my code I load a list of emails and it is divided in groups.
When I expand the group (the blue button of each group) the background is not covering the whole anymore.
In my computer this is the behaviour, however, in the jsfiddle I created for you to check, the background is not even covering it with the box un-expanded.

I was pretty sure that `height:100vh;` should be doing its work: covering the 100% of vertical space of the screen. But it's not the desired behaviour.

The fiddle is right here: https://jsfiddle.net/nseLa6o0/
For your convenience I have created a list of emails that you load from the top button, so the boxes will appear, please download it from here: https://gofile.io/d/xT1rWa

Comment: instead of using `height: 100vh;` try `min-height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.backg` style into

```css
.backg{
    background-color: rgba(65, 0, 11, 0.883);
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! But why, why height is not working but min-height does?

Comment: Your body's height is based on its content size. If you set `height: 100vh;` then, it will always have the same size - `100vh`, but if you set `min-height: 100vh;` then, it will have `100vh` if the body's content size is less than `100vh` and will have the content size if it's bigger than `100vh`.